# hudson.model.UpdateCenter#updateDefaultSite: Upgrading Jenkins. Failed to update the default Update Site 'default'. Plugin upgrades may fail

Tags: jenkins-2

How do I start the Jenkins process in offline mode on one of my servers?

I am trying to start Jenkins by running command java -jar jenkins.war, but it is failing at the below warning because of no connectivity.

Is there any way to skip this plugin upgrade through the internet and bring the Jenkins up and running?

````
2021-04-27 16:53:43.490+0000 [id=64]    WARNING hudson.model.UpdateCenter#updateDefaultSite: Upgrading Jenkins. Failed to update the default Update Site 'default'. Plugin upgrades may fail.
2021-04-27 16:53:43.490+0000 [id=64]    WARNING hudson.model.UpdateCenter#updateDefaultSite: Upgrading Jenkins. Failed to update the default Update Site 'default'. Plugin upgrades may fail.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:116)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:218)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:213)
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.updateDefaultSite(UpdateCenter.java:2611)
        at jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init(SetupWizard.java:212)
        at jenkins.install.InstallState$InitialSecuritySetup.initializeState(InstallState.java:168)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setInstallState(Jenkins.java:1104)
        at jenkins.install.InstallUtil.proceedToNextStateFrom(InstallUtil.java:98)
        at jenkins.install.InstallState$Unknown.initializeState(InstallState.java:86)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:3356)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-27 16:53:43.491+0000 [id=53]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2021-04-27 16:53:43.494+0000 [id=92]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: The attempt #1 to do the action check updates server failed with an allowed exception:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:116)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:218)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:213)
        at hudson.PluginManager.checkUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1882)
        at hudson.util.Retrier.start(Retrier.java:63)
        at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1853)
        at jenkins.DailyCheck.execute(DailyCheck.java:93)
        at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork.lambda$doRun$0(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:100)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-27 16:53:43.494+0000 [id=92]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Calling the listener of the allowed exception 'connect timed out' at the attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
2021-04-27 16:53:43.497+0000 [id=92]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Attempted the action check updates server for 1 time(s) with no success
2021-04-27 16:53:43.499+0000 [id=92]    SEVERE  hudson.PluginManager#doCheckUpdatesServer: Error checking update sites for 1 attempt(s). Last exception was: SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2021-04-27 16:53:43.504+0000 [id=36]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
2021-04-27 16:53:43.504+0000 [id=92]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Download metadata. 20,249 ms
2021-04-27 16:54:13.279+0000 [id=106]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Started Periodic background build discarder
2021-04-27 16:54:13.280+0000 [id=106]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 1 ms```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass all of these arguments before the -jar argument, otherwise they will be ignored. Example:

java -Dhudson.footerURL=http://example.org -jar jenkins.war